# How to fix OutlinedTextField value not changing?

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose

I have an OutlinedTextField whose value is provided by a property in my ViewModel. However the value is not changing even after I type something on the keyboard of my physical device. The value always remains blank.
I wonder what I'm doing wrong.
Below is my code.

HouseEvent

```
sealed interface HouseEvent {
  data class OnDescriptionChanged(val description: String): HouseEvent
}
```

HouseViewModel

```
val house: House? by mutableStateOf(null)

fun onEvent(event: HouseEvent) {
  when(event) {
    is HouseState.OnDescriptionChanged -> {
      house = house.copy(
        description = event.description
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Navigation composable

```
val viewModel = viewModel<HouseViewModel>()

HouseEditScreen(
  house = viewModel.house, 
  onEvent = viewModel::onEvent
)
```

HouseEditScreen

```
@Composable
HouseEditScreen(
  house: House?, 
  onEvent: (HouseEvent) -> Unit
) {

  OutlinedTextField(
    value = house?.description ?: "",
    onValueChange = { description ->
      onEvent(HouseEvent.OnDescriptionChanged(description)
    }
  )

}
```

Using a MutableStateFlow approach works but it meant I had to redeclare every property in my House class in the House state file.

I expect the value of the OutlinedTextField to be updated as soon as I type something on the keyboard

Comment: You can't use the `by` keyword for a MutableState variable because then you can not change it it's better to just use`=` instead

Answer (score 2):

The `house` property in your ViewModel is declared as `val`, which means you cannot change it:

```kotlin
val house: House? by mutableStateOf(null)
```

which would result in a compilation error here:

```kotlin
house = house.copy(
    description = event.description
)
```

unless you have some other `house` variable there.

Comment: I found the solution. I hadn't initialized house. Once I did that in the init block of HouseViewModel everything worked as expected